# "Unable to enable CICP on your project" - Google Cloud Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity

I am trying to enable the Identity Platform for my google cloud project. I keep getting the following error.

> "We are unable to enable CICP on your project, please try again later"

When I enabled the platform for a similar project (prod vs dev) it forced a popup to "`enable CICP on firebase`". Is there a way to force this popup or enable CICP using google cloud shell?

I have searched through google documentation as well as numerous forums for how to enable CICP using other methods including shell commands but can only find generic articles on how to enable the Identity Platform by clicking the "enable" button.

Edit: As suggested here is some more info. Billing is enabled, I am project owner, I have waited over a week, and project is region us-central.

Comment: The message says "please try again later". How long have you waited? What region are you in? Are you a Project Owner? Edit your question with more details.

Comment: I am having basically the same issue.  Several days trying, same error message when trying to enable.  Not sure why question had negative rating.  I upped it to get back to zero stars.

Comment: Did this get resolved? I am having the same problem.